# How to use a form input as a query parameter

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT MemberID 
FROM tbl_member 
WHERE MemberID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT tbl_classregistration.MemberID
                       FROM tbl_member 
                       INNER JOIN (tbl_classes 
                       INNER JOIN tbl_classregistration ON tbl_classes.ClassID = tbl_classregistration.ClassID) ON tbl_member.MemberID = tbl_classregistration.MemberID
                       GROUP BY tbl_classregistration.ClassID, tbl_classregistration.MemberID
                       HAVING (((tbl_classregistration.ClassID) = [Enter ClassID])))
```

Currently it takes the users parameter of classID but I want it to it from a specific form being "Forms![ClassRegistration]![txt_classid]"

Comment: provide more details please, question is not clear

Comment: I just need it to use the input of a form which is my class registration form to take the input as the parameter instead of having to enter a ClassID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be what you are referring to:

```
select MemberID from tbl_member where MemberID not in (SELECT DISTINCT tbl_classregistration.MemberID
FROM tbl_member INNER JOIN (tbl_classes INNER JOIN tbl_classregistration ON tbl_classes.ClassID = tbl_classregistration.ClassID) ON tbl_member.MemberID = tbl_classregistration.MemberID
GROUP BY tbl_classregistration.ClassID, tbl_classregistration.MemberID
HAVING (((tbl_classregistration.ClassID)=[Forms]![ClassRegistration]![txt_classid])))
```